# How to remove multiple \n from end of string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I used `chomp` to remove multiple `"\n"` from a string, but it only removes one. How can I remove multiple `"\n"` characters from a string?

My string looks like:

```
"Ttyyuhhhjhhhh\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

Comment: I see you are rather new to Stackoverflow (incidentally, so am I). Remember that after asking a question, once/if you receive an answer that truly answers your question, is a good idea to approve it. @gargvipan

Answer (score 8):

The method [`strip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip) will take care of removing **all leading and trailing white spaces** for you.

If you only want to remove the `\n` from the end of the string you can use a regexp such as:

```
string.gsub!(/(\n*)$/, '')
```

or [`rstrip!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rstrip)

```
string.rstrip!
```

Comment: Well, "...leading and trailing *white space..."*.

Comment: You are right, I always thought of white space as referring to only horizontal space, but I [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) now that vertical is also included in the definition. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: `(\n*)` is needlessly complex. There is no need to group `\n`, nor do you care about the case where there is no new-line so use `\n` by itself: `sub(/\n+$/, '')` is all that's needed.

Comment: @theTinMan IMO is the whole use of regular expression needlessly complex, why not to use `*strip` methods to actually *strip* the string?

Comment: Both ways are presented in this answer, regular expressions and ```strip```.

Comment: @heelhook using the regular expression for such a trivial task is simply wrong. I don't say a word about the second part of your answer. A solution is also to create a webservice in jboss and pass the string to it :-)

Comment: This answer is misleading. `rstrip` and `rstrip!` remove all trailing whitespace, not just nelines.

Answer (score 8):

As you need to strip from the end of your string, use [`rstrip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rstrip)

```
str = "Ttyyuhhhjhhhh\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
str.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to remove newlines, and not other whitespace, `strip` and `rstrip` (which remove all whitespace) are not the answer. The regex `/\n+\Z/` will match any number of newlines at the end of a string:

```rb
str1 = "text \t\n\n\n"
# => "text \t\n\n\n"
str1.sub(/\n+\Z/, '')
# => "text \t"
```

Note that this works (and **without** the multiline regexp modifier `/m`) on multi-line strings as well, leaving newlines in the middle of the string intact:

```rb
str2 = str1 + str1 + str1
# => "text \t\n\n\ntext \t\n\n\ntext \t\n\n\n"
str2.sub(/\n+\Z/, '')
# => "text \t\n\n\ntext \t\n\n\ntext \t"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
"Ttyyuhhhjhhhh\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n".gsub(/\n$/,'')
```

Comment: The regex is wrong. `/$\n/` would find new-lines after the current line, not new-lines at the end of the current line. Instead, you need `/\n$/`.